# Android Emulator 4.1.2 Root?

Tags: android, emulation, root

How to root Android 4.1.2 is, as I said in the title?

```
adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system  
adb push su /system/xbin/su  
adb shell chmod 06755 /system  
adb shell chmod 06755 /system/xbin/su
```

this code works Android 2 but doesn't work on 4.1.2.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're trying to do this in the emulator (because of the "emulator" tag). Have you tried simply running `adb root` ?

Comment: yes im tried.But superuser dont work.

Answer (score 0):

Change and Try using the following line:
`adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`